# Angular not updating with Dev Extreme data-grid columns and views

Tags: angular, typescript, devextreme, angular-changedetection, dx-data-grid

component.html

```
<dx-data-grid>
 <dxi-column *ngFor="let column of columns">
  // creating columns
 </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

component.ts

```
public setupColumnsAndState(newColumns[]: any, state: any) {
 columns = newColumns[];
 // Is there something that could be done here to update datagrid columns?
 this.datagrid.instance.state(state); //state has columns
}
```

When setting the datagrid state, if the columns within the state do not exist yet in the datagrid (ex. state has 5 columns and datagrid only has 3), then when setting the state, the datagrid filters them out.

So in this example (what I think is happening)

- columns are being set
- page has yet to create the columns
- datagrid does not have updated columns
- when setting state, the datagrid columns are empty so state columns are being filtered.

I've tried looking into ngZone and changeDetectorRef, but I couldn't get it to work properly and am unsure if these would even help in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like what follows. Set up a ChangeDetectorRef and and call the detectChanges where you have your current comment.

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
public someFn() {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
  // ngOnChanges will be called
}
```

Information comes from: [This Article](https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/ngonchanges-only-runs-when-the-input-change-comes-from-a-template-binding-like-component-8797b759ba0b)

Comment: Seems like such an easy solution... Not sure how I didn't try this